# Multiply effect kinteicjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I want to know have to make multiply effects with kineticjs framework.
My problem is next:

I have background which is image
I need to draw polygon over image and apply multiply effect on that new polygon.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can apply image filters by:**

- Reading the rgb pixels of the image you wish to filter-- context.getImageData
- Alter the rgb pixel values according to your filter
- Replace the pixels in the image with the altered pixels-- context.putImageData

**Here is how to apply a multiply filter to an image:**

```
function multiply(R,G,B){
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    data = imgData.data;
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
        data[i  ] = R*data[i]/255;
        data[i+1] = G*data[i+1]/255;
        data[i+2] = B*data[i+2]/255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}

// Usage:
multiply(130,130,200)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I not sure, how you understood me, but I need to implement blending with multiply.

Comment: Chuckle, yes I read your question wrong!  See my changed answer showing how to apply a multiply filter to an image.

Comment: Ok, but how to apply multiply just on part of image where is polygon?

Comment: Just limit the pixels you get to the polygon bounding box:  context.getImageData(polyX,polyY,polyWidth,polyHeight) and context.putImageData(imageData,polyX,polyY);

Comment: BTW, if you want to multiply the existing background image using the non-transparent polygon pixels, you would have to draw your polygon to a separate canvas.  Then use getImageData on **both canvases** and conditionally multiply only the non-transparent  pixels from the separate canvas.